# Remove JSON object properties that match regular expression in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

Given an example json object like:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Pablo",
  "UnwantedProperty1XOXO": true,
  "UnwantedProperty2XOXO": false,
  ...
}
```

I want to remove every property that ends in `XOXO` (so the regex would be something like `/.+XOXO$`).

**How can I remove all the properties with names that match a regular expression with PowerShell?** (either with a JSON object or PowerShell object)

I can remove properties from a PowerShell object like this but it doesn't seem to work with a regular expressions:
`$myObject.PSObject.Properties.Remove("someProperty")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The most robust solution is *not* to use regex-based text parsing**, which is *brittle* (a property-value pair may be spread across multiple lines, a *value* may accidentally match a property *name* to exclude).

Instead:

- **Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to perform proper JSON parsing** into custom objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances) ...
- ... and then **use `Select-Object -Exclude` with a *wildcard pattern* to exclude the properties of non-interest** ...
- ... and convert back to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`, if needed.

```
Get-Content -Raw file.json |
  ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty *XOXO |
      ConvertTo-Json
```

<sup>Note: The `[-Property] *` argument passed to `Select-Object` is only required in *Windows PowerShell*; PowerShell *Core* sensibly *assumes* `-Property *` when only `-ExcludeProperty` is specified.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can import the content of the file with `Get-Content` and then use the built in regex operators to do this.

```
$data = Get-Content C:\Users\U394282\Desktop\test.json
```

We want to set `$unwantedProps` to an array (in this example it's using the @() symbol to encapsulate the results, and so it always has a `.Count` property

```
$unwantedProps = @($data | ? { $_ -match 'XOXO'})

if($unwantedProps.Count -gt 0)
{
    $cleanedData = $data -notmatch 'XOXO'    
    return $cleanedData
}
else {
    return
}
```

Depending on the structure of the JSON file and what index position gets removed as a result, you might also want to have a helper function that will check if the very last item has a comma, making the JSON invalid: