# using powershell how to remove property in json when under multiple levels

Tags: json, powershell

Using powershell how remove a property **synonymMaps** in a json.

```
{
    "name":  "dev-contentitem-text-index",
    "defaultScoringProfile":  null,
    "fields":  [
                   {
                       "name":  "id",
                       "type":  "Edm.String",
                       "searchable":  false,
                       "filterable":  false,
                       "retrievable":  true,
                       "sortable":  false,
                       "facetable":  false,
                       "key":  true,
                       "indexAnalyzer":  null,
                       "searchAnalyzer":  null,
                       "analyzer":  null,
                       "synonymMaps":  ""
                   },
                   {
                       "name":  "myvalue",
                       "type":  "Edm.String",
                       "searchable":  false,
                       "filterable":  false,
                       "retrievable":  true,
                       "sortable":  true,
                       "facetable":  false,
                       "key":  true,
                       "indexAnalyzer":  null,
                       "searchAnalyzer":  null,
                       "analyzer":  null,
                       "synonymMaps":  ""
                   }
               ]
}
```

I tried which remove synonymMaps but I loose the top level property name and defaultScoringProfile. I need the whole thing intact but with synonymMaps removed.

```
$indexDefinition  = Get-Content $storedIndex.FullName

$indexDefinition = ($indexDefinition| ConvertFrom-Json)

$indexDefinition.fields|Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty "*synonymMaps*"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove JSON object properties that match regular expression in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975894/remove-json-object-properties-that-match-regular-expression-in-powershell)

Comment: this is what I tried Get-Content $storedIndex.FullName -Raw|ConvertFrom-Json|Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty * synonymMaps * | ConvertTo-Json. It did not work. I think i have go the depth wrong could you help me refine it. not sure how to

Comment: the second option worked better but then it does not remove the extra comma in the last line before synonmMaps

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested json-structure, you need recursive function for it:

```
$json = @"
{
    "name":  "dev-contentitem-text-index",
    "defaultScoringProfile":  null,
    "fields":  [
                   {
                       "name":  "id",
                       "type":  "Edm.String",
                       "searchable":  false,
                       "filterable":  false,
                       "retrievable":  true,
                       "sortable":  false,
                       "facetable":  false,
                       "key":  true,
                       "indexAnalyzer":  null,
                       "searchAnalyzer":  null,
                       "analyzer":  null,
                       "synonymMaps":  ""
                   },
                   {
                       "name":  "myvalue",
                       "type":  "Edm.String",
                       "searchable":  false,
                       "filterable":  false,
                       "retrievable":  true,
                       "sortable":  true,
                       "facetable":  false,
                       "key":  true,
                       "indexAnalyzer":  null,
                       "searchAnalyzer":  null,
                       "analyzer":  null,
                       "synonymMaps":  ""
                   }
               ]
}

"@

function Remove-Property {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
    [object] $inputObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
    [string] $namePattern
  )
  process {
    foreach ($element in $inputObject) {
      foreach ($propName in $element.psobject.Properties.Name) {
        if ($propName -like $namePattern) {
          $element.psobject.Properties.Remove($propName)
        }
        else {
            if( $element.$propName ) {
                Remove-Property -InputObject $element.$propName -namePattern $NamePattern | Out-Null
            }
        }
      }
    }
    return $inputObject
  }
}


# convert JSON to PSObject
$obj     = ConvertFrom-Json $json

# remove entries
$newObj  = $obj | Remove-Property -NamePattern 'synonymMaps*'

# convert back to json
$newJson = $newObj | ConvertTo-Json
```